# Recreate force touch buttons from iPhone X lock screen

Tags: ios, swift, iphone-x

Is it possible to recreate the behavior of the flashlight button from iphone X lockscreen?
I am of course interested only in using public APIs supported by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Try this !

```
  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        guard let touchPosition = touches.first else {  return  }

        // Check if 3D touch is available
        if .available == self.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability{

            // Perform action for tap with force
            if touch.force > 1.0{
                // Touch pressure gretaer than normal tap

                // TODO:
            }
        }
    }
```

You can also check this method: `touch.maximumPossibleForce`

> Force touch value 1.0 is the default as per the documentation. [average force](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitouch/1618110-force)

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/tracking_the_force_of_3d_touch_events)